# What does lseek() mean for a directory file descriptor?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, file-descriptor

According to `strace`, `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END) = 9223372036854775807` when `fd` refers to a directory. Why is this syscall succeeding at all? What does `lseek()` mean for a dir fd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my test system, if you use `opendir()`, and `readdir()` through all the entries in the directory, `telldir()` then returns the same value:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int fd = open(".", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("open");
    return 1;
  }

  off_t o = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
  if (o == (off_t)-1) {
    perror("lseek");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Via lseek: %ld\n", (long)o);
  close(fd);

  DIR *d = opendir(".");
  if (!d) {
    perror("opendir");
    return 1;
  }
  while (readdir(d)) {
  }

  printf("via telldir: %ld\n", telldir(d));
  closedir(d);

  return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
Via lseek: 9223372036854775807
via telldir: 9223372036854775807
```

Quoting from the [`telldir(3)` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/telldir.3.html):

> In early filesystems, the value returned by `telldir()` was a simple file offset within a directory.  Modern filesystems use tree or hash structures, rather than flat tables, to represent directories.  On such filesystems, the value returned by `telldir()` (and used internally by `readdir(3)`) is a "cookie" that is used by the implementation to derive a position within a directory.  **Application programs should treat this strictly as an opaque value, making no assumptions about its contents.**

It's a magic number that indicates that the index into the directory's contents is at the end. Don't count on the number always being the same, or being portable. It's a black box. And stick with the dirent API for traversing directory contents unless you *really* know exactly what you're doing (Under the hood on Linux + glibc, `opendir(3)` calls `openat(2)` on the directory, `readdir(3)` fetches information about its contents with `getdents(2)`, and `seekdir(3)` calls `lseek(2)`, but that's just implementation details)